# How to fix two titles combining when button pressed?

Tags: ios, swift

*Here is all of the code for this app as it said in the title I have to titles that collide and combine when a certain button is pressed how can i fix this?*

*This is the code I'm using, also I'm not sure where the Error is accruing so I just showed all of the code for the App*

```
`import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



@IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
   
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

let coffeeTimes = ["Decaf": 5]
var timer = Timer()
var player: AVAudioPlayer!
var totalTime = 0
var secondsPassed = 0

@IBAction func coffeeSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
   
    timer.invalidate()
    
    let coffee = sender.titleLabel?.text
    totalTime = coffeeTimes[coffee!]!
        titleLabel.text = coffee
    
    
    progressBar.progress = 0.0
    secondsPassed = 0
    titleLabel.text = coffee
    
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target:self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo:nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func updateTimer() {
    if secondsPassed < totalTime {
        secondsPassed += 1
        progressBar.progress = Float(secondsPassed) / Float(totalTime)
        print(Float(secondsPassed) / Float(totalTime))
    } else {
        timer.invalidate()
        titleLabel.text = "check coffee"
        
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "alarm_sound", withExtension: "mp3")
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        player.play()
    }
}
```

}

}

`

Comment: It looks like you have two labels on top of each other potentially. Either hide them accordingly to your logic as needed or just use one label to keep it simple if the label does nothing special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Storyboard issue. You don't have an outlet for your label titled "Coffee Timer" in your code, but it obviously exists. You need to go to your `Main.storyboard` file and open the sidebar on the left, select your titleLabel, and move it elsewhere. I'm assuming by default, `titleLabel.text` is empty which is why you can't see it overlapping on your Storyboard.

[image: Main.storyboard]